# Получить данные с таблицы сразу в один массив/строку+проблема с Implode

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!

У меня возникла проблема, дело в том, что я делаю небольшое приложение, и перед мной на данном этапе стоит задания вывода данных пользователей по их id. 
Для этого я хочу использовать метод [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get), и передавать одним запросом все данные пользователей. Но проблема в том, что нужно как-то упаковать все данные с массива в строку и для этого есть функция implode, но дело в том, что при использовании mysql_fetch_assoc я получаю лишь одну ячейку всех столбцов, а не все сразу.

Как можно решить эту проблему? Допускаю, что перезаписью массива в другой. 
Но, возможно, есть функция? P.S. О mysqli_fetch_all читал, но с ней не вышло+она на многих хостингах отключается.
Сам код:

```
<?php 
require_once('db.php');
$sql_connection = dbConnect();
$_REQUEST['viewer_id'] = 2;

function getUsers($user_id, $sql_connection){
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `catch_up` WHERE `owner_id` LIKE ".$user_id." ";
    $sql_response = mysql_query($sql_query);

    return $sql_response;
}

function showUsers($sql_response,$sql_connection){

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response)){
    // Тут должен быть вывод данных
    }

}

$sql_response = getUsers($_REQUEST['viewer_id'],$sql_connection);
showUsers($sql_response,$sql_connection);


?>
```

UPD:

Пока попробовал:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response)) {
    $data[] = $row;

    return $data;
}
```

+потом var_dump массива

Но всё-равно вывело одну запись, вместо двух :(

UPD 2: Я ракан, return в цикл поставил. Сейчас исправлю.
UPD 3:

Решили уже хоть как-то проблему первую, теперь проблем с Implode.

При implode почему-то не склеивает всё в строку, а возвращает при var_dump: string(11) "Array,Array" 
Сам код(скриншот): pp.vk.me/c630925/v630925489/448b7/J6bHjj_eNmY.jpg 
Что не так? Сам массив с данными содержит следующий вид:
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["v_id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1](https://vk.com/dev/users.get)=> array(1) { ["v_id"]=> string(1) "2" } }

Comment: Результат сложить в массив и с ним работать
`while ($rows[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_response));
print_r($rows);`
Ну и обратите внимание что методы являются устаревшими.

Comment: @Bookin, спасибо Вам, добрый человек. Этот вариант намного оптимизированный будет!

Насчёт того, что это устарело я читал, но годной альтернативы не нашёл :(

Comment: Интересно что вы через пару лет будете делать, когда нормальные хостинги перейдут на более свежий php в котом вообще нет функций mysql_*. Выбирайте хостинги где уже сейчас есть PDO и используйте функции PDO, например fetchAll.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за совет, об этом я знаю и постараюсь в ближайшее время дополнить знания, ибо сам понимаю, что это всё устаревшие методы. Просто, ещё только учусь.

Comment: И кстати интересно зачем вам like, id по идее число, зачем его искать как строку. И да, _никогда_ не подставляйте переменные непосредственно в текст. 50% сайтов взламывают именно из за подобного кода. Используйте bindParam

Comment: @Mike, хм, а какой оператор для поисках числовых данных в SQL не подскажите? 
Сам LIKE я использую, ибо БД со временем будет содержать огромное кол-во записей, и думаю, что лучше запросом в SQL найти нужные данные, нежели в PHP всё обрабатывать. 

Судя по гуглу, bindParam используется в PDO? Хм, а что насчёт просто MySQL? В плане взлома вряд ли в данном приложении, авторизация и пр. на стороне ВК,  а у меня пользователю доступен ввод лишь в одно int'овое поле. 

Спасибо Вам за ценные советы!

Comment: `owner_id = $user_id` для чисел используется обычный знак равенства и числа не надо заключать в кавычки. like используется только при поиске частей строки в тексте. Да, в mysql_* нет bindParam, только в mysqli и pdo. Если есть хоть малейший шанс, что на вход вам придет не число, а лучше просто на всякий случай предварительно проверяйте что в переменных именно то, что ожидаете. другого пути для mysql_* боюсь нет

Comment: Господа, ещё вопрос, у меня при implode почему-то не склеивает всё в строку, а возвращает при var_dump: `string(11) "Array,Array"` 
Сам код(скриншот): https://pp.vk.me/c630925/v630925489/448b7/J6bHjj_eNmY.jpg || Что не так? Сам массив с данными содержит следующий вид:
`array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["v_id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["v_id"]=> string(1) "2" } } `

Answer (score 1):

1. вместо mysql_query надо использовать PDO
2. вместо implode надо использовать json_encode

поэтому пишем.

```
function getUsers($user_id, $pdo){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `catch_up` WHERE `owner_id` = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$user_id]);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
echo json_encode(getUsers($_REQUEST['viewer_id'], $pdo));
```

[Как соединяться с PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#connect)